# Delivery value input to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have written a simple page which have a form input. While a user prints text at the form a script gets request on  server and take JSON data. I need to pass a value from the input to a function which reprocess the value.

```js
var search = document.querySelector('#search');

function iReceived(msg) {
  var mass = msg.data;
  mass.map(function(e) {
    var city = document.querySelector('#city');
    var newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.innerHTML = e.Description;
    city.appendChild(newLi);
  });
};

function Foo(e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: "https://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/",
    data: {
      "modelName": "Address",
      "calledMethod": "getCities",
      "methodProperties": {}, 
      "apiKey": "6f94a6391cb5134ee68ddb7924de2a3d"
    },
    success: iReceived, /* this function I would like to pass value input
                            but I can write just a reference on this
                            function without () and arguments */
  });
  console.log(e.target.value);
};

search.oninput = Foo;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="search" onchange="Foo()">
</form>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="city"></div>
```

May have I built this program a bad way?

Comment: Does it work? Or not? What's your question ?

Comment: I don't see the value of `#search` being used in `$.ajax`, so yes, I would say this won't work. And you have many lines requiring rewriting for performance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be on codereview.stackexchange

Comment: @mmm This works, but just in a browser. In codepen it doesn't work, server don't pass request. I want get a  input's value and use this parse  a list of name citys which  returns server. I need pass data to function "iReceived" and i don't know how do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)?

> **success** *Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR
>   )*
>    A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets
>   passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted
>   according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback
>   function, if specified; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR
>   (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the
>   success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will
>   be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event. timeout

So in your case you would modify your `Foo()` functions `success` method like below

```
function Foo(e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: "https://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/",
    data: {
      "modelName": "Address",
      "calledMethod": "getCities",
      "methodProperties": {}, 
      "apiKey": "6f94a6391cb5134ee68ddb7924de2a3d"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      // the data is the data returned from the server
      // do whatever you want with the data here
      // get the value you need for iReceived here.
      iReceived(value); /* this function I would like to pass value input
                            but I can write just a reference on this
                            function without () and arguments */
    }
  });
  console.log(e.target.value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet but here is a good starting point:

You should start by having the user submitting their data with a button before it runs the function. As soon as you input any text into that box the json request fires off with one character, then two, and so on.

Currently what ever you put into that box returns 2070 results that are all objects, I'm not sure of the formatting of the api but you should try to call just the part of the objects/array that you need.

Comment: I want get a data which print a user in form and use this data for build dropdown list of name city.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Can you try to explain it differently?

Comment: @ D. Can User a begin prints a name city in form  which he would like choose. I need sort list of name city use text which the user input form and build just list of  sorted name city.  Further  the user click on name city choose it. OMG, sorry for my English.